# Java Concurrency issues when updating video control UI while JMF video is playing

Tags: java, concurrency, jmf

I'm building a video player in pure Java around JMF, with completely custom UI controls.  Everything was working great until I put in a JLabel which updates the current play time in hh:mm:ss.ss format.  The label updates acceptably, but occasionally halts for 10+ seconds at at a time, which is unacceptable.

The JMF `Player` is created in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()...` block.  Here is the UI updating code:

```
protected void createUIUpdater() {
    System.out.println("Creating UI updating worker thread");
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(mediaPlayer.getState() == Controller.Started) {
                updatePlayPosition();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println("Sleep interrupted!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("UI Updater thread finished.");
        }
    }.start();
}

protected void updatePlayPosition() {
    Movie movie = timelineEditor.getMovie();
    movie.setInsertionPoint(Rational.valueOf(mediaPlayer.getMediaTime().getSeconds()));
    updateTimeLabel();
}

protected void updateTimeLabel() {
    Movie movie = timelineEditor.getMovie();
    Rational time = movie == null ? new Rational(0,1) : movie.getInsertionPoint();
    // ... hours/minutes/seconds calculated
    timeLabel.setText((hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes)
            + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds)
            + "." + (frame < 10 ? "0" + frame : frame));
}
```

which is called in a `ControllerListener` on a `StartEvent`.  During this time the audio/video are playing.

I'm admittedly a bit of a novice when it comes to concurrency in Java, and I'm sure there's a better way of handling this separate thread.  Any suggestions?

Comment: try to call the label invalidate and then validate after each update.

Comment: The problem isn't that the JLabel doesn't redraw, rather that the Thread seems to "hang".  I put in a sysout statement in `updateTimeLabel()` and when the problem occurs, the sysouts aren't being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closer inspection, it seems that my thread is executing fine, it is just getting blocked occasionally on `mediaPlayer.getMediaTime()` (where `mediaPlayer` is a `javax.media.Player`).

Turns out, calling `mediaPlayer.getMediaNanoseconds()` does not block.

Answer (score 0):

you could replace your Thread/sleep with ScheduledExecutorService:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

because when using sleep there is no guarantee as to how long the thread will actually sleep , it may take more the the time you specify to return to the running status.

Comment: Tried this, seems to be the same problem.  Seems like the executing thread is getting blocked at times.